# Debian: xinitrc doesn't start: Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault)

Tags: debian, xorg, virtualbox, openbox, xinit

I have a VM at virtualbox in Windows 11

The VM is Debian 11 (bulleye or something like that)

After installing (great!) and configure the resolution as it told here: https://www.ronaldtoussaint.nl/2018/01/24/increasing-the-screen-resolution-of-linux-console-with-grub-in-virtualbox/

It worked!

But now i want to make the command "startx" run openbox

I installed xorg and xinit

And installed openbox

But when i run the command "startx" it freezes and then crashes, returning to the Unix shell

I created the file .xinitrc with the following lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
userresources=$HOME/.Xresources
usermodmap=$HOME/.Xmodmap
sysresources=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xresources
sysmodmap=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xmodmap

if [ -f $sysresources ]; then
        xrdb -merge $sysresource
fi

if [ -f $sysmodmap ]; then
        xmodmap $sysmodmap
fi

if [ -f "$userresources" ]; then
        xrdb -merge "$userresources"

fi

if [ -f "$usermodmap" ]; then
        xmodmap "$usermodmap"
fi



if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
        for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
                [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
        done
        unset f
fi

openbox-session
```

Here are the logs

```
[    64.143]
X.Org X Server 1.20.11
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    64.143] Build Operating System: linux Debian
[    64.143] Current Operating System: Linux UNIX-lenovo-w11-virtualmachine 5.10.0-16-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.127-2 (2022-07-23) x86_64
[    64.143] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-16-amd64 root=UUID=bff5418e-26ea-4a76-9d83-32fabfe28fef ro quiet nomodeset
[    64.143] Build Date: 16 December 2021  05:08:23PM
[    64.143] xorg-server 2:1.20.11-1+deb11u1 (https://www.debian.org/support)
[    64.143] Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
[    64.143]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    64.143] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    64.144] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Aug  3 12:39:24 2022
[    64.147] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    64.148] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    64.148] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    64.148] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    64.148] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    64.149] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using a default monitor configuration.
[    64.149] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    64.149] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    64.149] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    64.149] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    64.152] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    64.152]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    64.155] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
        built-ins
[    64.155] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    64.155] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
        If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    64.155] (II) Loader magic: 0x5593fbb7ee40
[    64.155] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    64.155]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    64.155]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.1
[    64.155]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    64.155]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    64.156] (++) using VT number 1

[    64.158] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_33
[    64.159] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 15ad:0405:15ad:0405 rev 0, Mem @ 0x80000000/134217728, 0x88400000/2097152, I/O @ 0x0000c170/16, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    64.160] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    64.161] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    64.169] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    64.169]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 1.0.0
[    64.169]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[    64.169] (==) Matched vmware as autoconfigured driver 0
[    64.169] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[    64.169] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[    64.169] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[    64.169] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    64.169] (II) LoadModule: "vmware"
[    64.169] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vmware_drv.so
[    64.310] (II) Module vmware: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    64.310]    compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 13.3.0
[    64.310]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    64.310]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[    64.310] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    64.310] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    64.312] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    64.312]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 1.20.11
[    64.312]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    64.312]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[    64.312] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    64.312] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    64.312] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    64.312]    compiled for 1.20.0, module version = 0.5.0
[    64.312]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    64.312]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[    64.312] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    64.312] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    64.313] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    64.313]    compiled for 1.20.9, module version = 2.5.0
[    64.313]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    64.313]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[    64.313] (II) vmware: driver for VMware SVGA: vmware0405, vmware0710
[    64.313] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    64.313] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    64.313] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    64.313] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    64.313] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    64.313] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    64.313] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    64.313] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    64.313] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    64.314] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    64.314]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 0.0.2
[    64.314]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[    64.314] (II) vmware(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
        "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    64.567] (EE) vmware(0): Failed to open drm.
[    64.567] (WW) vmware(0): Disabling 3D support.
[    64.567] (WW) vmware(0): Disabling Render Acceleration.
[    64.567] (WW) vmware(0): Disabling RandR12+ support.
[    64.567] (--) vmware(0): VMware SVGA regs at (0xc170, 0xc171)
[    64.567] (II) Loading sub module "vgahw"
[    64.567] (II) LoadModule: "vgahw"
[    64.567] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvgahw.so
[    64.570] (II) Module vgahw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    64.570]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 0.1.0
[    64.570]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[    64.573] (--) vmware(0): caps:  0x00F6C2A0
[    64.573] (--) vmware(0): depth: 24
[    64.573] (--) vmware(0): bpp:   32
[    64.573] (--) vmware(0): vram:  134217728
[    64.573] (--) vmware(0): pbase: 0x80000000
[    64.573] (--) vmware(0): mwidt: 5632
[    64.573] (--) vmware(0): mheig: 5632
[    64.573] (--) vmware(0): depth: 24
[    64.573] (--) vmware(0): bpp:   32
[    64.573] (--) vmware(0): w.red: 8
[    64.573] (--) vmware(0): w.grn: 8
[    64.573] (--) vmware(0): w.blu: 8
[    64.573] (--) vmware(0): vis:   4
[    64.573] (==) vmware(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    64.573] (==) vmware(0): RGB weight 888
[    64.573] (==) vmware(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    64.573] (==) vmware(0): Using HW cursor
[    64.573] (==) vmware(0): Will set up a driver mode with dimensions 1920x1080.
[    64.573] (==) vmware(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    64.573] (II) vmware(0): Clock range:   0.00 to 400000.00 MHz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Virtual size is 1920x1080 (pitch 5632)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0): *Driver mode "vmwlegacy-default-1920x1080": 156.1 MHz, 65.0 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "vmwlegacy-default-1920x1080"x60.0  156.08  1920 1921 1922 2402  1080 1081 1082 1083 (65.0 kHz ez)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "5120x2880": 1276.5 MHz, 178.9 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "5120x2880"x60.0  1276.50  5120 5560 6128 7136  2880 2883 2888 2982 -hsync +vsync (178.9 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "4096x2304": 813.0 MHz, 143.1 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "4096x2304"x60.0  813.00  4096 4440 4888 5680  2304 2307 2312 2386 -hsync +vsync (143.1 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "3840x2160": 712.8 MHz, 134.2 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "3840x2160"x60.0  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync (134.2 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "3200x1800": 492.0 MHz, 111.8 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "3200x1800"x60.0  492.00  3200 3456 3800 4400  1800 1803 1808 1865 -hsync +vsync (111.8 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "2880x1620": 396.2 MHz, 100.7 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "2880x1620"x60.0  396.25  2880 3096 3408 3936  1620 1623 1628 1679 -hsync +vsync (100.7 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "2560x1600": 348.5 MHz, 99.5 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "2560x1600"x60.0  348.50  2560 2760 3032 3504  1600 1603 1609 1658 -hsync +vsync (99.5 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "2560x1440": 312.2 MHz, 89.5 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "2560x1440"x60.0  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync (89.5 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "2048x1536": 388.0 MHz, 137.0 kHz, 85.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "2048x1536"x85.0  388.04  2048 2216 2440 2832  1536 1537 1540 1612 -hsync +vsync (137.0 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "2048x1536": 340.5 MHz, 120.2 kHz, 75.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "2048x1536"x75.0  340.48  2048 2216 2440 2832  1536 1537 1540 1603 -hsync +vsync (120.2 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "2048x1536": 266.9 MHz, 95.3 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "2048x1536"x60.0  266.95  2048 2200 2424 2800  1536 1537 1540 1589 -hsync +vsync (95.3 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1920x1440": 341.4 MHz, 128.5 kHz, 85.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1920x1440"x85.0  341.35  1920 2072 2288 2656  1440 1441 1444 1512 -hsync +vsync (128.5 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1920x1440": 297.0 MHz, 112.5 kHz, 75.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1920x1440"x75.0  297.00  1920 2064 2288 2640  1440 1441 1444 1500 -hsync +vsync (112.5 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1920x1440": 234.0 MHz, 90.0 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1920x1440"x60.0  234.00  1920 2048 2256 2600  1440 1441 1444 1500 -hsync +vsync (90.0 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1856x1392": 288.0 MHz, 112.5 kHz, 75.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1856x1392"x75.0  288.00  1856 1984 2208 2560  1392 1393 1396 1500 -hsync +vsync (112.5 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1856x1392": 218.3 MHz, 86.4 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1856x1392"x60.0  218.30  1856 1952 2176 2528  1392 1393 1396 1439 -hsync +vsync (86.4 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1792x1344": 261.0 MHz, 106.3 kHz, 75.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1792x1344"x75.0  261.00  1792 1888 2104 2456  1344 1345 1348 1417 -hsync +vsync (106.3 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1792x1344": 204.8 MHz, 83.7 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1792x1344"x60.0  204.80  1792 1920 2120 2448  1344 1345 1348 1394 -hsync +vsync (83.7 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "2048x1152": 197.0 MHz, 71.6 kHz, 59.9 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "2048x1152"x59.9  197.00  2048 2184 2400 2752  1152 1155 1160 1195 -hsync +vsync (71.6 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1920x1200": 193.2 MHz, 74.6 kHz, 59.9 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1920x1200"x59.9  193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync (74.6 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1920x1080": 173.0 MHz, 67.2 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync (67.2 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1600x1200": 229.5 MHz, 106.2 kHz, 85.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x85.0  229.50  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (106.2 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1600x1200": 202.5 MHz, 93.8 kHz, 75.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x75.0  202.50  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (93.8 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1600x1200": 189.0 MHz, 87.5 kHz, 70.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x70.0  189.00  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (87.5 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1600x1200": 175.5 MHz, 81.2 kHz, 65.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x65.0  175.50  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (81.2 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1600x1200": 162.0 MHz, 75.0 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x60.0  162.00  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (75.0 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1680x1050": 214.8 MHz, 93.9 kHz, 84.9 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x84.9  214.75  1680 1808 1984 2288  1050 1053 1059 1105 -hsync +vsync (93.9 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1680x1050": 187.0 MHz, 82.3 kHz, 74.9 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x74.9  187.00  1680 1800 1976 2272  1050 1053 1059 1099 -hsync +vsync (82.3 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1680x1050": 174.0 MHz, 76.6 kHz, 69.9 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x69.9  174.00  1680 1800 1976 2272  1050 1053 1059 1096 -hsync +vsync (76.6 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1680x1050": 146.2 MHz, 65.3 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x60.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1680x1050": 146.2 MHz, 65.3 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x60.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1400x1050": 179.3 MHz, 93.8 kHz, 85.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1400x1050"x85.0  179.26  1400 1504 1656 1912  1050 1051 1054 1103 -hsync +vsync (93.8 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1400x1050": 155.8 MHz, 81.5 kHz, 74.8 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1400x1050"x74.8  155.80  1400 1464 1784 1912  1050 1052 1064 1090 +hsync +vsync (81.5 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1400x1050": 145.1 MHz, 76.5 kHz, 70.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1400x1050"x70.0  145.06  1400 1496 1648 1896  1050 1051 1054 1093 -hsync +vsync (76.5 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1400x1050": 122.0 MHz, 64.9 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1400x1050"x60.0  122.00  1400 1488 1640 1880  1050 1052 1064 1082 +hsync +vsync (64.9 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1600x900": 118.2 MHz, 56.0 kHz, 59.9 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1600x900"x59.9  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync (56.0 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1280x1024": 157.5 MHz, 91.1 kHz, 85.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x85.0  157.50  1280 1344 1504 1728  1024 1025 1028 1072 +hsync +vsync (91.1 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1280x1024": 135.0 MHz, 80.0 kHz, 75.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x75.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1280x1024": 108.0 MHz, 64.0 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1440x900": 106.5 MHz, 55.9 kHz, 59.9 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1440x900"x59.9  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1400x900": 103.5 MHz, 56.0 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1400x900"x60.0  103.50  1400 1480 1624 1848  900 903 913 934 -hsync +vsync (56.0 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1280x960": 148.5 MHz, 85.9 kHz, 85.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1280x960"x85.0  148.50  1280 1344 1504 1728  960 961 964 1011 +hsync +vsync (85.9 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1280x960": 108.0 MHz, 60.0 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1280x960"x60.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1368x768": 85.2 MHz, 47.8 kHz, 59.9 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1368x768"x59.9   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync (47.8 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1360x768": 84.8 MHz, 47.7 kHz, 59.8 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1360x768"x59.8   84.75  1360 1432 1568 1776  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync (47.7 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1280x800": 83.5 MHz, 49.7 kHz, 59.8 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1280x800"x59.8   83.50  1280 1352 1480 1680  800 803 809 831 -hsync +vsync (49.7 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1152x864": 143.5 MHz, 91.5 kHz, 100.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1152x864"x100.0  143.47  1152 1232 1360 1568  864 865 868 915 -hsync +vsync (91.5 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1152x864": 121.5 MHz, 77.5 kHz, 85.1 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1152x864"x85.1  121.50  1152 1216 1344 1568  864 865 868 911 +hsync -vsync (77.5 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1152x864": 119.7 MHz, 77.1 kHz, 85.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1152x864"x85.0  119.65  1152 1224 1352 1552  864 865 868 907 -hsync +vsync (77.1 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1152x864": 108.0 MHz, 67.5 kHz, 75.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1152x864"x75.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1152x864": 105.0 MHz, 67.6 kHz, 75.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1152x864"x75.0  104.99  1152 1224 1352 1552  864 865 868 902 -hsync +vsync (67.6 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1152x864": 96.8 MHz, 63.0 kHz, 70.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1152x864"x70.0   96.77  1152 1224 1344 1536  864 865 868 900 -hsync +vsync (63.0 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1152x864": 81.6 MHz, 53.7 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1152x864"x60.0   81.62  1152 1216 1336 1520  864 865 868 895 -hsync +vsync (53.7 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1280x720": 74.5 MHz, 44.8 kHz, 59.9 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1280x720"x59.9   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync (44.8 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1024x768": 94.5 MHz, 68.7 kHz, 85.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1024x768"x85.0   94.50  1024 1072 1168 1376  768 769 772 808 +hsync +vsync (68.7 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1024x768": 78.8 MHz, 60.0 kHz, 75.0 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1024x768"x75.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1024x768": 75.0 MHz, 56.5 kHz, 70.1 Hz
[    64.574] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1024x768"x70.1   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz d)
[    64.574] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1024x768": 65.0 MHz, 48.4 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[    64.575] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz d)
[    64.575] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "1024x576": 46.5 MHz, 35.9 kHz, 59.9 Hz
[    64.575] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1024x576"x59.9   46.50  1024 1064 1160 1296  576 579 584 599 -hsync +vsync (35.9 kHz d)
[    64.575] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "832x624": 57.3 MHz, 49.7 kHz, 74.6 Hz
[    64.575] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "832x624"x74.6   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz d)
[    64.575] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "960x540": 40.8 MHz, 33.5 kHz, 59.6 Hz
[    64.575] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "960x540"x59.6   40.75  960 992 1088 1216  540 543 548 562 -hsync +vsync (33.5 kHz d)
[    64.575] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "800x600": 56.3 MHz, 53.7 kHz, 85.1 Hz
[    64.575] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "800x600"x85.1   56.30  800 832 896 1048  600 601 604 631 +hsync +vsync (53.7 kHz d)
[    64.575] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "800x600": 49.5 MHz, 46.9 kHz, 75.0 Hz
[    64.575] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "800x600"x75.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz d)
[    64.575] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "800x600": 50.0 MHz, 48.1 kHz, 72.2 Hz
[    64.575] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "800x600"x72.2   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz d)
[    64.575] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "800x600": 40.0 MHz, 37.9 kHz, 60.3 Hz
[    64.575] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz d)
[    64.575] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "800x600": 36.0 MHz, 35.2 kHz, 56.2 Hz
[    64.575] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "800x600"x56.2   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz d)
[    64.575] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "864x486": 32.5 MHz, 30.3 kHz, 59.9 Hz
[    64.575] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "864x486"x59.9   32.50  864 888 968 1072  486 489 494 506 -hsync +vsync (30.3 kHz d)
[    64.575] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "640x480": 36.0 MHz, 43.3 kHz, 85.0 Hz
[    64.575] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "640x480"x85.0   36.00  640 696 752 832  480 481 484 509 -hsync -vsync (43.3 kHz d)
[    64.575] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "640x480": 31.5 MHz, 37.5 kHz, 75.0 Hz
[    64.575] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "640x480"x75.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz d)
[    64.575] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "640x480": 31.5 MHz, 37.9 kHz, 72.8 Hz
[    64.575] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "640x480"x72.8   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz d)
[    64.575] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "640x480": 25.2 MHz, 31.5 kHz, 59.9 Hz
[    64.575] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz d)
[    64.575] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "720x405": 22.5 MHz, 25.1 kHz, 59.5 Hz
[    64.575] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "720x405"x59.5   22.50  720 744 808 896  405 408 413 422 -hsync +vsync (25.1 kHz d)
[    64.575] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "720x400": 35.5 MHz, 37.9 kHz, 85.0 Hz
[    64.575] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "720x400"x85.0   35.50  720 756 828 936  400 401 404 446 -hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz d)
[    64.575] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "640x400": 31.5 MHz, 37.9 kHz, 85.1 Hz
[    64.575] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "640x400"x85.1   31.50  640 672 736 832  400 401 404 445 -hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz d)
[    64.575] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "640x360": 18.0 MHz, 22.5 kHz, 59.8 Hz
[    64.575] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "640x360"x59.8   18.00  640 664 720 800  360 363 368 376 -hsync +vsync (22.5 kHz d)
[    64.575] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "640x360": 17.8 MHz, 22.2 kHz, 59.3 Hz
[    64.575] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "640x360"x59.3   17.75  640 688 720 800  360 363 368 374 +hsync -vsync (22.2 kHz d)
[    64.575] (**) vmware(0):  Default mode "640x350": 31.5 MHz, 37.9 kHz, 85.1 Hz
[    64.575] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "640x350"x85.1   31.50  640 672 736 832  350 382 385 445 +hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz d)
[    64.575] (==) vmware(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    64.575] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    64.575] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    64.575] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    64.577] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    64.577]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 1.0.0
[    64.577]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    64.577] (II) Loading sub module "shadowfb"
[    64.577] (II) LoadModule: "shadowfb"
[    64.577] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadowfb.so
[    64.577] (II) Module shadowfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    64.577]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 1.0.0
[    64.577]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    64.577] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    64.577] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    64.577] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    64.577] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    64.577] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    64.577] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    64.577] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    64.577] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    64.577] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[    64.577] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    64.577] (II) Unloading vesa
[    64.577] (II) vmware(0): Initialized VMWARE_CTRL extension version 0.2
[    64.577] (II) vmware(0): vgaHWGetIOBase: hwp->IOBase is 0x03d0
[    64.580] (EE) vmware(0): Unable to map frame buffer BAR. Invalid argument (22)
[    64.580] (EE)
[    64.580] (EE) Backtrace:
[    64.581] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x135) [0x5593fbaf1435]
[    64.582] (EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (funlockfile+0x50) [0x7fdf12713140]
[    64.582] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__nss_database_lookup+0x2865c) [0x7fdf1269b03c]
[    64.582] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[    64.582] (EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vmware_drv.so (?+0x0) [0x7fdf11ddf6ef]
[    64.582] (EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (AddScreen+0xd7) [0x5593fb98d817]
[    64.582] (EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitOutput+0x27f) [0x5593fb9cf16f]
[    64.582] (EE) 6: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitFonts+0x1cc) [0x5593fb99139c]
[    64.582] (EE) 7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xea) [0x7fdf1255ed0a]
[    64.582] (EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x2a) [0x5593fb97ad1a]
[    64.582] (EE)
[    64.582] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
[    64.582] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[    64.582] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[    64.582] (EE)
[    64.582] (EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
[    64.582] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    64.582] (EE)
[    64.628] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

I fixed, i tried removing the "nomodeset" in the GRUB Parameters and worked!